# Trim() a list of strings using dynamic query language to produce a trimmed IQueryable<string>

Tags: c#, linq, string, trim

Is this possible, or am I just trying to way overly shorten my code?

I thought it might be something like:

```
IQueryable<string> trimmedStrs = untrimmedStrsArr.AsQueryable<string>().All(s => s.Trim());
```

But that's no good :(

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think you want just:

```
IEnumerable<string> trimmed = untrimmedStrsArr.Select(s => s.Trim());
```

If you have in-memory collection such as list or array, then you can work with them using LINQ methods for `IEnumerable<T>`, because these process data in memory. Queryable is useful when working with databases (e.g. using LINQ to SQL).

You can find a good documentation on various methods on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods.aspx). The following should explain why you need `Select` instead of `All`:

- `All` - Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.
- `Select` - Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

Answer (score 3):

This one seemed to work for me:

```
IQueryable<string> trimmed = untrimmed.AsQueryable<string>().Select(m => m.Trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

`All` is not the right method to do this. It is a predicate, returning true if every item in the collection matches the condition you give in the parameter. Use

```
IQueryable<string> trimmedStrs = untrimmedStrsArr.AsQueryable<string>().Select(s => s.Trim());
```